# How does Windows File Explorer know the orientation of a photo when there does not appear to be any EXIF data?

Tags: php, orientation, photo, exif

I have developed a website in PHP which displays the many thousands of photos I've taken over the years. To date I've had no problem with orientation - landscape and portrait pictures all display correctly.

I have recently started editing some of the photos and it has changed some of their orientation. I have now modified my code to handle EXIF's 'Orientation' data (using the function 'correctImageOrientation' created by Wes on Stack Overflow - many thanks Wes!) to rotate the photos accordingly and it works well.

However, some of my edited photos do not now have EXIF Orientation data so I can't use it to rotate the photo but yet File Explorer somehow knows the correct orientation and displays the photo correctly.
My question, therefore, is where does File Explorer get the photos orientation from and how do I access it from PHP?

Comment: I believe this is a question for photography section of SE. But it may be the resolution 1920x1080 vs 1080x1920? Just a guess

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, so will post as answer.

Exif data is just metadata which is used by specific devices. Otherwise it can be stripped. You could explore [this workaround from the comment section in php's manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#117355):

```
$orientation = 1;
if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if (isset($exif['Orientation'])) $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
} else if (preg_match('@\x12\x01\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00(.)\x00\x00\x00@', file_get_contents($filename), $matches)) {
    $orientation = ord($matches[1]);
}
```

Comment: No need to excuse it as an answer. +1 from me. It holds better quality than other upvoted answers here. PS. Now you can comment :-)

Comment: Appreciate the thought, just new account, so also familiar with suitable formatting. Hope it helps though, it seems to be quality/upvoted answer which I assume helped 5 other people.